# MongoDB find documents which have multiple keys in a field

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

This is how a documents looks like in my dataset:

```
{
  username: 'stack',
  attempts: { 1517761701: false, 1512341532: true }
}

{
  username: 'overflow',
  attempts: { 1217563721: false }
}
```

Now, I want to retrieve every document in my dataset where `attempts` contains more than óne key. So the query should return the document of user 'stack' but not of user 'overflow'. What query can I apply here?

Comment: Try `db.collection.find({$expr:{$gt:[{$size:{$objectToArray:"$attempts"}}, 0]}})` in 3.6

Answer (score 1):

try `$objectToArray` to convert object to array and count the number of keys if you are using mongo 3.6+

```
db.cols.aggregate(
  [
    {$addFields: {count : {$size : {$ifNull : [{$objectToArray : "$attempts"}, []]}}}},
    {$match: {count : {$gt : 1}}},
    {$project: {count : 0}}
  ]
)
```

Comment: Correction!. `$objectToArray` is supported in version 3.6. please see https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/objectToArray/#exp._S_objectToArray

Answer (score 0):

Use **[`$redact`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/redact/)** for a single pipeline:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        "$redact": {
            "$cond": [
                {
                    "$gt": [
                        { "$size": { 
                            "$objectToArray": {
                                "$ifNull": [
                                    "$attempts",
                                    { }
                                ]
                            }
                        } },
                        1
                    ]
                },
                "$$KEEP",
                "$$PRUNE"
            ]
        }
    }
])
```

Answer (score 0):

Convert `attempts` to an array, `$unwind` and then use `$sortByCount` to do all the work..

```
db.collection_name.aggregate( [ 
{ $addFields : { array : { $objectToArray : "$attempts"} } },
{ $unwind : "$array" },  
{ $sortByCount : "$username" },
{ $match : { count : { $gte : 2 } } }
])
```

Outputs:

```
{
    "_id" : "stack",
    "count" : 2
}
```